# Is it possible to write a route in NextJS using Golang?

Tags: go, next.js, vercel

is it possible to write a route in NextJS using Golang?

Like the folder structure would be:

- pages

  - api

    - name.go

And we can query /api/name and get a response back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not something NextJS provides. But if you are hosting your page on Vercel, you can use their [Go Runtime for Serverless Functions](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/functions/serverless-functions/runtimes/go) to achieve the same thing.

You can do this by having the file path be `/api/name.go` instead of `/pages/api/name.go`.